# What permissions are required to edit an object-backed Form in Palantir Foundry?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have a Foundry Form backed by an object, being able to write changes to it. What permissions do I need to grant my colleagues for them to be able to edit the Form? Is editor on the Form enough, or do they also need to be editors on the object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To create a form you need permission to create resources in the Compass folder the form will be located in. You also need a specific permission based on the backing data for the form:

For an object-backed form, you need `fforms:form-definition:create-phonograph-form`

Comment: Thank you for answering these @Arun. I've been giving you +1 on your good answers for encouragement :)